# Replace Temp with Query

Tags: java, refactoring

The Replace Temp with Query refactoring method is recommended quite widely now but 
seems to be very inefficient for very little gain.

The method from the Martin Fowler's site gives the following example:

Extract the expression into a method. Replace all references to the temp with the expression. The new method can then be used in other methods.

```
    double basePrice = _quantity * _itemPrice;
    if (basePrice > 1000)
        return basePrice * 0.95;
    else
        return basePrice * 0.98;
```

becomes

```
    if (basePrice() > 1000)
        return basePrice() * 0.95;
    else
        return basePrice() * 0.98;


double basePrice() {
    return _quantity * _itemPrice;
}
```

Why is this a good idea? surely it means the calculation is needlessly repeated and you have the overhead of calling a function. I know CPU cycles
are cheap but throwing them away like this seems careless?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

It's a refactoring that is important as it is a refactoring towards single responsibility, it's a resolution of DRY fail!

The main problem with temps (esp. in naive code using long methods, hundreds of lines long!) is that they are mutable, local state.  The obvious risk (as discussed by Fowler?) is that someone might make a change mid way down a long method, and break something at the end. (Have seen this cost incurred)

There are no tests, this method has myriad dependencies - what a mess! :)

Remove temp is about refactoring towards single responsibility.

Example - today I found a bug and it relates to passing the *wrong temp variable* into a service. If I remove temps (there are several, all strings), that bug (oversight) just can't happen.

The reason my method is holding a temp variable is that it's doing work it shouldn't ... and this logic is repeated by similar classes... is it all consistent?  NO!

By removing temp, I'll also refactor code into a class with appropriate responsibility, that can be covered 110% by a few simple tests.

No huge fixture to test something trivial

If I call something expensive, I'll return the result as a value object / aggregate.  The 'temp code' should be internalized by the aggregate, probably.

So remove temp pushes you into centralized (singular) responsibility -> SOLID!

Answer (score 7):

I am re-reading Refactoring right now and one reason is the following quote from the end of `Extract Method` p.116.

Background: He describes that it is difficult to `Extract Method` if the code to extract uses local variables.

> Temporary variables often are so plentiful that they make extraction very awkward. In these cases I try to reduce the temps by using Replace Temp with Query (120). ...

So one refactoring might depend on first doing another refactoring which itself is not obvious. Another example is `Inline Method` before Replace `Method with Method Object`.

Answer (score 6):

You (both original asker, and James Curran) are missing that in this particular example, the calculation is not repeated. Either the code goes down one branch of the `if`, and calls `basePrice()`, which performs the calculation. Or the code goes down the other branch of the `if` and the calculation is performed there instead.

The multiplication is done regardless, but still only once. Just as in the temp version.

Yes, it's good to be aware that queries are by default not cached and that temps are inherently a form of caching. In this particular example that distinction doesn't matter. The advantage of caching (such as temps) is that it can provide CPU cycle savings (not really in this case, as far as the multiplication itself goes, I mean—in terms of calls, stack jumps etc, then sure… depending on the compiler). The disadvantage of caching is that it can give you out of date or wrong data if you are sloppy. That's in addition to the specific disadvantages with temps that Fowler mentions (that they are local, both temporally and lexically).

What I usually do is that I code in queries most of the time and when I see that I *do* call a particular query multiple times (unlike this example, where it's in separate conditional branches), I can use a temp if it's local or introduce memoization or another type of cache system (such as a simple global variable or class member) if I need to access it in a wider, less local scope.

That's when the reverse to this refactoring, "Replace Query with Temp", comes in handy.

Comment: Appreciate the idea of temps as a form of caching. But you still have one additional calculation over a temp, in the if condition.

Comment: Well, that's specific to this particular case which a case where I would use a query.
I use a temp when it's like `frotz = SuperExpensive(); if frotz = baz then frotz+bar, else frotz-bar` or w/e

Answer (score 5):

Having read Fowler's [webpage on it](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTempWithQuery.html), I can see no advantage to doing it that way.  The only possible gain is by isolating an expression which may be used often into one spot, but that would be best handled by :

```
    double basePrice = basePrice();
    if (basePrice > 1000)
            return basePrice * 0.95;
    else
            return basePrice * 0.98;
```

Fowler offers no explanation why his revised code is better than the original, other than to read his book.

Comment: Your way seems to make more sense, but I think Fowler is simply trying to illustrate, albeit extremely, what it looks like when he abstracts the baseprice calculation to its own method.

Comment: Thank you for speculating and shedding some light, but if you want to give an authoritative answer to this, than at least you should HAVE (read) Fowler's book, since your link of his web version of it just provides the same info that the OP's question already provides. I consider @kenno's and other answer superior to this one.

Answer (score 5):

I think most of the utility of this refactoring does not come from applying it by itself but as a step towards an Extract Method which is extremely common and useful. On the cases where local variable stand in the way of Extract Method or complicate it by additional parameters, 'replace temp with query helps' to make Extract Method easier. Also in those cases, the query method that is generated gets reused by two different methods which are result of extract method.

Answer (score 5):

There is something more about Replace Temp with Query in Refactoring book and it is:

> You may be concerned about performance in this case. As with other performance issues, let it
>   slide for the moment. Nine times out of ten, it won't matter. When it does matter, you will fix the
>   problem during optimization. With your code better factored, you will often find more powerful
>   optimizations, which you would have missed without refactoring. If worse comes to worse, it's
>   very easy to put the temp back.

Answer (score 3):

It's intended to be more revealing of the intention of the code. In some cases it can be abused but not likely. for example you could update the queries for the 5% and 2% discounts with queries but in the name of the methods you could describe in the name  reason for the discount. remember, it may be obvious today but in 6 months it might not be so - as I say - its not a matter if I forget, but when I forget.

```
  if (basePrice() > 1000)
     return bigTicketDiscount()
  else
     return regularDiscount()

double bigTicketDiscount(){
  return basePrice() * 0.95;
}

double regularDiscount(){
  return basePrice() * 0.98
}
```

Comment: The problem is, if you read Fowler page on the matter (link in my answer), you'll see that code cited in the question (which you imply is abusing the concept) comes directly from Fowler.  You suggestion seems to be changing the focus of what Fowler seems to be saying.

Comment: my point on abuse was that its possible if you start doing it in the extreme its not good and I could see its abuse.  I htink however its intention is to simplify code that is complex and obscuring - it is a technique after all and if it doesnt work for you, dont do it

Answer (score 0):

It really seems to me that by doing this you are helping to make a single purpose to your original method; It no longer is responsible for calculating the basePrice and the discount price (or whatever it is that it is calculating).  This is an example of sacrificing some CPU cycles to make the code more maintainable.  The "wasted" cpu cycles are probably not something you'll notice for one and also it's possible the compiler could optimize it (maybe by noticing that the method is relatively simple and instead of calling the method it inserts the actual code (more like a macro).  Anyway, these types of optimizations are best left to machines, leaving people with cleaner code to work on.

Comment: James Curran's example is clean enough for most taste, no? I think doing it like that will give the highest "value for CPU cycles": for the CPU it's only 1 stack jump more expensive, but you still got your readability.